# Any reasons for crew on space warships?

Tags: warfare, science-fiction, spaceships, space-warfare

I was thinking why there would be crew on a space warships when everything can be automated by even basic AI.

Without crew you can pull all the gees you want with your torch-drive and no need for artificial gravity centrifuges. I thought about maybe dozens of auto-warship frigates and destroyers around a single flagship with crew controlling the different groups of warships meanwhile all the ships provide protection and point defense for the flagship.

So is there really a need for crew on space warships as depicted in many military-science fiction stories? Just slap a fusion drive down with a bank of thermonuclear warheads completely covered by CIWS and laser point defense and coil guns.

When the light-lag gets too long just let the AI take over, it'll probably even do better than the flagship crew anyways. Maybe the warships can even deploy mirrors to protect the flagship from the incoming laser fire. I can't find a real reason for crew apart for maybe repair and just in general story telling. I mean it does provide for some awesome war stories.

Comment: This seems very close to https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/113502/627.

Comment: This seems precisely the point made by Iain Banks' [Culture Novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_series)

Comment: The point of the Star Trek TOS episode "[The Ultimate Computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ultimate_Computer)" was that you can't replace human intuition with AI.  But let's assume your AI is built using [Clarkean Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) and its abilities are equal to or beyond those of a human.  The only rational answer is "there are none," which is tangentally related to the Star Trek TNG episode "[The Nth Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nth_Degree_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))".

Comment: sure, if drama counts as a reason

Comment: Oh, @jean, entertainment for the AI... I'll laugh for a week.  Thanks!

Comment: NOTE TO VTCers.  I completely disagree that this is a duplicate of the stated question, which specifically asks why live crews would be used to fight wars.  There is a subtle but important difference between these questions.  @Mołot, if you disagree with me, please post your reasons.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a very important question I want answered as well, ans as JBH says this is an importantly different question compared to the others. I personally only have two not terribly good reasons: AI including weak AI cant be trusted (and non-AI programming is too easily countered), or theres a mcguffin in play that prevent high levels of computer power (I like introducing high fluctuations that mess with small electronics so you return to larger cirquits offering less modern era computerpower that suit your setting).

Comment: @HDE226868, it might be similar but I think that it is stated better.  The other question is on hold.  This one can be answered since the only reason to close it is because it is similar to a question that people aren't allowed to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue about a robotic fighting ship is control.  If it isn't smart enough to act on it's own, you need to be close enough that the light speed lag won't affect fighting performance.  If it is too smart, how do you control it?

**Not Smart:**

We had fly by wire missiles and torpedoes.  They would be the beginning of this.  You had to stay within "wire" distance of the target.

then we had radio controlled weapons (missiles, torpedoes, drones).  The problem with this tech is distance (signal strength and time delay) and interference.  Theoretically, an enemy could intercept communication and/or give false commands to the weapon.

To get around this, you need to program in just enough smarts to go after the target once designated.  We kind of have this now.  We have missiles that, once targeted, follow or even switch targets on their own.  You have to either be close enough to set the target or give it enough smarts to be able to select it's own targets.  However, this starts to get into the next category.

**Smart:**

If the weapon can select its own targets, you better be sure that it selects the **correct** targets.

If it selects a non-enemy target, or worse, gets captured and turned on you, you will not be having a good day.

I suggest you read Fred Saberhagen's [Berserker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berserker_(Saberhagen)) series.  It is about self replicating AI war machines that outlast their makers and continue their war.

The Exterminator movie has a similar take on this theme.

There are a lot of stories in which smart weapons go wrong.  Some because of buggy software, some with battle damage and others where they were reprogrammed.  Unless you want to repeat those stories, you better make sure that you take them into account to show how that didn't happen.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out for me. Helps me draw the line between the types of AI on such warships. I was thinking more of this type of AI: if enemy detected then plot course to intercept and destroy, if unable, contact nearest human operator, if not possible: defend to best ability. (But at the same time this AI would not be very smart and could not compensate, be creative, etc.)

Comment: Here's a problem for you to solve (or weave into your story):  **Can compensate** leads to self programming (that can go all kinds of wrong).  **Can't compensate** means that the enemy may figure out a way to outsmart all of the weapons.

Comment: That's important too. What if it is AI vs AI? Like I mentioned in the comment under [this answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/113549/49508) . Here there are no humans to fight anymore, similarly this happens at a point in my story resulting in auto defense and attack systems fighting each other over the remains.

Comment: It could happen for a short while.  However, think of how much infrastructure it takes to support one fighting craft.  Is it all automated?  How mines the minerals, then smelts them and then builds the parts that then need to be assembled and then delivered?

Comment: Nope, the infrastructure is upheld by human coordination. Sure rearming and refuel is automated but that could only go on until the stations run out of ammo and fuel. It is more of a cold-war gone nuclear scenario. Every automated weapon is launched if humans are compromised. So every orbital thermonuclear platform and every interplanetary destroyer goes ahead and fires its payload into the enemy until both sides run out of ammo or every planet in the system is so irradiated that nothing works anymore and every combat unit is dead. Kind of the moral I try to convey about current automation.

Comment: Basically it would only last for a short time just like you said.

Comment: It's possible.  Just look at the video you linked to in the other answer.  The AI was there to take over from a disabled pilot.  If that AI gets good enough, why put the pilot in there?   Your proposal would go from AI assisting the pilot to AI becoming the pilot.

Comment: I think the pilot is there more to assist the AI if it fails at its task or is outsmarted. I think the AI in the video is not very advanced and follows a specific set of rules. More of an algorithm than a proper thinking machine. Kind of like ICBMs. But since no pilot is present, the AI is technically the pilot and a remnant of the past hatred left by humans. Of course that's not science that's more me being moral about it.

Comment: You could put a human in there if it was worth making the ship less effective by slowing the turns and acceleration just so a meat babysitter can survive the combat.

Answer (score 2):

Expense is one reason. It depends on your world, but in ours, robots with fine motor control are pricey, and human repairmen are much less so. Not to mention the fact that humans can innovate and find ways around the "irreplaceable" part that broke down, while robots can't. (unless they're "truly" intelligent and not merely imitations) A ship fully reliant on AI would also be unlikely to be capable of colonization or transport missions without crippling its capabilities. Even if the pros outweighed the cost in other use-cases, in these cases, (where you have to maintain a livable space for humans, anyway) a human crew is probably much more cost effective without losing much in the way of effectiveness. (especially if they have an AI to assist them)

Comment: See the Isaac Asimov short story “The Feeling of Power”, in which a society that has only AI-controlled weapons wins a war by re-inventing human-piloted weapons, which are much cheaper and easier to produce.

Comment: @MikeScott That does provide for some ethical and moral points of war that you could cover in a story which can show how it effects society and people. Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't have strong A.I., and we have no reason to believe you can at this point in time, then tasks that require intuition rather than procedural logic require humans not machines. Also if you reverse this slightly if you can have strong A.I. it's probably too smart to go to war, war is not logical but you can get humans to fight if you tell them it's "right" enough times. Either way you need emotional, biological beings if you want to go to war.

Comment: That makes sense. Would the idea with the flagship work? Maybe smaller flagships controlling small fleets of warships which split from the main fleet?

Comment: @zertofi Only if you have instantaneous communication over large distances (those measured in things like light-minutes), otherwise the light-lag kills you, fast.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no particular reason to believe that an AI would make a good warship crew. It would be walking a very fine line between being smart enough to be as effective as a human crew, and being smart enough to immediately desert. Or the three laws of robotics may apply, or the society may value AIs equally with humans (e.g Iain M Banks’s Culture) and not want to put them in harm’s way.

Comment: What if the AI's sole purpose is to attack and defend against the enemy? It only has the intelligent capacity to figure out were to fire and how to intercept the enemy, nothing else. Would't this be more effective than crew? Kinda like assembly line robots, they only do the task at hand because that is what they are programmed to do.

Comment: @zertofi Such an AI likely wouldn’t be smart enough to innovate or respond to the unexpected, so it would need a human crew for that.

Comment: If the AI resembles current technology in any way, it's easy to set the AI's goals in such a way that it would not "want" to desert. Current AI (not sci-fi it's-a-robot-with-a-soul AI) only "wants" what it's been programmed to "want."

Comment: I see, so you could have a central control point in a fleet like the flagship I described. Things like point-defense is handled by AI meanwhile the tactics themselves are handled by the crew. Maybe there are multiple central warships with crew with dozens of auto-warships.

Comment: @Josh But if the AI resembles current technology in any way, then it’s far too stupid and predictable to win a battle. We’re talking about AIs that are many orders of magnitude smarter than anything we have now.

Comment: @zertofi You say central control point, I say single point of failure. If the enemy only has to knock out one ship to win a fleet battle, that one ship won’t last long.

Comment: @MikeScott So what would you recommend? Fully crewed ships or a lot of ships that are a mix of both crewed and automated/outside controlled ships? You could use it as a tactic were the enemy doesn't know which one is the drone (but I'm not a scientist nor tactician)

Comment: @zertofi No one can say, because we don’t have such AIs or any idea how to make them, so we can only speculate. For worldbuilding purposes, just pick whichever option you want for the kind of world you’re building. You can always justify it by making up characteristics of your AIs to fit.

Comment: I was thinking about AI war and such and this short CGI movie came to mind called 'Fortress' by Dima Fedotof. It is about how the entire human race is dead but the automated bombers and fighters still fight over the dead cities. The bomber's pilot is dead so the craft automatically flies itself to the drop zone and defends against an enemy fighter. It would be better explained if I just show it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pyMNIFZTQkg

Answer (score 0):

there are concurring factors:

- **cost**: an AI costs quite some money, you don't want the enemy to hack it undisturbed or, worse, that a BSOD or a critical patch install makes it useless in the middle of the battlefield
- **lack of trust**: do you trust that the AI will be always patriotic and loyal, 100% hacking proof?
- **tactical improvisation**: an algorithm can be cracked and its pattern discovered and neutralized. Creative thinking not.

Comment: "an algorithm can be cracked and its pattern discovered and neutralized. Creative thinking not." Damn that's a cool sounding phrase, mind of I use it in my writing?

Comment: @zertofi, you can use it. I got inspiration from http://dilbert.com/strip/2012-03-18

Comment: Psychology can be applied to dictate the outcome. No matter how much "creative thinking" you throw at it, the machine can look at your options, analyse your flight patterns from approach and onwards and predict the likeliest outcome(s). The best (worst) part is that the AI can predict all outcomes that will mean something and deal with those causing a no-win scenario. Creativity would only mean you picked an outcome with a low prediction and is at best a stay of execution.